# Search point inside a multiplygon loaded with ST_GeomFromGeoJSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I'm using MySQL 8 and with this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `geometry` multipolygon NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  SPATIAL KEY `country_geometry_index` (`geometry`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And `geometry` data is inserted using `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` from here https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/geojson/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson

Example:

```sql
INSERT INTO `country`
SET
    `name` = "Spain",
    `geometry` = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson[spain].geometry);
```

Now I want to search if a point is inside any country polygon with:

```sql
select *
from `country`
where ST_Contains(`geometry`, POINT(42.000000, -8.000000))
limit 1;
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR 3033 (HY000): Binary geometry function st_contains given two geometries of different srids: 4326 and 0, which should have been identical.
```

Some help? Thanks!

UPDATE 1:

As @Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo say, I need to set SRID. Now I haven't errors on query, but not results:

```sql
select *
from `country`
where ST_Contains(`geometry`, ST_SRID(POINT(42.000000, -8.000000), 4326))
limit 1;
```

I will check `geometry` values tomorrow :)

UPDATE 2:

As @Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo say, I need to invert POINT coordinates:

```sql
select *
from `country`
where ST_Contains(`geometry`, ST_SRID(POINT(-8.000000, 42.000000), 4326))
limit 1;
```

Comment: You should set the srid to the point geometry: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213814

Comment: You have flipped your coordinates. You should call `POINT(longitude latitude)`  not the reverse way.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo it works :) thanks!